# how to have my gpu in virtualbox ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, virtualbox, gpu

So i have being tired of my AMD GPU not unlocking its full potential on ubuntu. my graphics card is an radeon r9 380. CPU is an I5. someone convinced me to use windows 10-virtual-box for gaming rather than dual booting it. how can i use my graphics card on virtual box?